# Two identical strings not shown as equal Javascript Meanjs

Tags: javascript, string, meanjs

This is an extremely simple and basic problem, to the extent that I am baffled as to what could be causing this behavior. In my MEANJS app, the user is being logged in using Passport. The User model has a simple authenticate method, which matches the entered password, with the user's password, after hashing it. This app is already in production, and there is nothing wrong with it. I have been facing an altogether different problem of not being able to update users, because Save fails as the password field is required, which when given, results in rehashing of the password. Point being, I haven't messed with the authenticate method in the least, it's the standard MEANJS authenticate function.

```
UserSchema.methods.authenticate = function(password) {
 console.log('password being authenticated is ' + password);
 console.log('Hash password is : ' + this.hashPassword(password));
 console.log('User\'s existing pwd is : ' + this.password);

 var ePwd = this.hashPassword(password);
 var uPwd = this.password;
 if(ePwd === uPwd){
    console.log('TRUE'); //THIS IS NOT DISPLAYED
 }
 return this.password === this.hashPassword(password);
};
```

This is not returning true, even though my passwords are exactly the same. To check and since I am logging the values I copy pasted them in my Chrome ScratchJS window just to verify and this displays correctly there:

```
var p1 = 'nkzm3dT0tjxOZ'; //hashPassword(password)
var p2 = 'nkzm3dT0tjxOZ';  //this.password
if(p1 === p2){console.log('TRUE');} //WORKS
```

Why on earth would this happen?? There can be no possible interference from any changes I may have made as the values are being retried right here. I am sure it is possibly something infinitely stupid, but this is really driving me up the wall. I would really appreciate any help, brickbats included.

Console output

```
password being authenticated is mypassword
Hash password is : nkzm3dT0tjxOZSRfsoNckNomgVouYvaw7WYEpqL4G6ovFTSDeosnxfHecNUhsvDWwcXIBzopsvLx1HZiX+

User's existing pwd is : nkzm3dT0tjxOZSRfsoNckNomgVouYvaw7WYEpqL4G6ovFTSDeosnxfHecNUhsvDWwcXIBzopsvLx1HZiX+
```

I must point out that this has been working PERFECTLY fine up until just a few hours ago.

TYPEOF result

```
typeof ePwd string
typeof uPwd string
```

Comment: what is the actual output of your console log statements. _put it in the question_.

Comment: `console.log(typeof ePwd, typeof uPwd )` post the result of that.

Comment: @SebastianNette Both are `string`. `var p1 = 'nkzm3dT0tjxOZ'; //hashPassword(password)
var p2 = 'nkzm3dT0tjxOZ';  //this.password`

Comment: Or if `p1` is not `string` use `p1.toString()`

Comment: They are probably not both strings. Hence why the type comparing `===` fails.

Comment: Updated question with more output, both are string, with no white space :(

Comment: Trim leading/trailing whitespaces, check type of both (make sure that both are string, if not use `toString()`),

Comment: I see a blank line between the "Hash password is" and "User's existing pwd is" lines of the output. Is there a newline at the end of `this.hashPassword(password)`? When outputting debug information like this, it can be helpful to put characters around your output so you can see where the string *really* ends, e.g. if it has trailing spaces.

Comment: Blank line is my bad, there is no line between the two in the output.

Comment: Ok so I added a trim() to both this.password and the hashPassword(password) and now it shows a match. It does not show a match of I just trim hashPassword(password), which does not make sense to me, as this.password is being retrieved from the database and should ideally not require any trimming.

Comment: @monologish it might be because one of your variable might be using `new String()`. If you use `b.trim()` at my code then it'll return true either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trim leading/trailing whitespaces from `epwd` and `upwd`.

Comment: There is no line there in the ouput, the entire hashed string was coming in two lines while copy pasting into the SO editor, so I left the blank line there by mistake after correcting the hash.

Comment: If you can add the trim suggestion to this answer I will mark it as the right one as you were the first one to suggest it. Don't know why it suddenly required this though :/

Answer (score 1):

When using the === operator you're comparing not only the string values but the objects them selves and if the objects differ then even though they look equal they are not.

To fix this use == to do a type conversion, then it should compare the string values of p1 and p2.